# Swift generic strange behaviour

Tags: swift, generics

I've found a strange swift generic behaviour:

```
protocol Textable {}

class Test { 
    init<T: NSObject>(values: [T]) where T: Textable {}
}

func test<T: NSObject>(value: T) where T: Textable {
    let values = [value]
    Test(values: [value]) // Cannot convert value of type '[T]' to expected argument type '[_]'
}
```

This code with error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[T]' to expected argument type '[_]'.

But if I change `Test(values: [value])` to `Test(values: values)`, it works fine. Maybe am I doing something wrong? Or it's just a swift's bug...

Created [issue](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3849?jql=) at Swift JIRA.

Comment: why do you want to set Test(values: [value]) to nothing?

Comment: It strangely works with: `let values = [value]; Test(values: values) `

Comment: It looks like it's something about having `T` constrained to both inherit from a class and conform to a protocol that the compiler doesn't like – in any case, you should definitely [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: @Hamish I've created the issue. Check the updated post.